# Youtube sound cutting out when using bluetooth headphones on Fedora

Tags: fedora, chrome, bluetooth, youtube

So when watching a YouTube video on my Fedora machine, the sound will cut out, and then a few second later a white loading circle will appear on the video. I suspect a related problem might be that when I try to listen to spotify, a similar problem arises where it says "The Current Song Cannot be Played" for every single song. These problems seemed to have cropped up since I moved the machine to a new office, so could a change in network cause them somehow? I also have noticed significantly increased lag.

Relevant details:
Browser: Chrome
Headphones: Bluetooth (any)
OS: Fedora 27

Thanks!

UPDATE: I was able to fix my problem by reducing the number of bluetooth devices (wireless usb mouse, needed to use a wired keyboard, as for some reason even the wireless usb keyboard was causing issues.) and moving my tower so that it had a direct line to my headphones without going through my desk.

Comment: That sounds like slooooow Internet.

Comment: Do you use wifi ? If Yes is it 5ghz or 2.4ghz ? Also is it the same with other sound source ? Spotify deezer any other vidéo provider ?

Comment: @MichaelHampton I should mention that the issues disappear if I plug my earbuds into the computer, or if I use the bluetooth speakers with a windows computer on the same internet. So it's some interaction between Fedora and the headphones. (As far as I can tell)


Kiwy I'm wired in via ethernet. The only two sound sources I've checked have been youtube and Spotify. Are there other benchmarks I should consider to nail down the issue?

Comment: I'd suggest updating to Fedora 28; there have been improvements and bug fixes in pretty much every subsystem which might be to blame here.

Comment: Unfortunately this is an office computer so I can't update the OS on my own. However I seem to have mistaken, and I'm actually only one iteration behind (Fedora 27). I'll try to bug the IT guys into letting my update to 28.

Comment: Please post your update as an answer, not as an update to the question

Comment: WiFi or Ethernet?  Also, note that Bluetooth, WiFi and "normal" wireless keyboards and mice all use the same frequency range.

Answer (score 0):

removing mic permission solved this for me.

Comment: Please [edit] your answer and state how you did this - what command or UI setting?